# Docusign Connect - Error - Delivery pending. Internal Connect Error

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect

I'm trying to create a webhook that updates the envelope on my system, but I'm having this issue:

Docusign Issue

[image: 1]

Has anyone ever had something similar?

Comment: How did you create the Connect configuration? do you get this error consistently ? when  you send the envelope? or when?

Answer (score 1):

I took a look about this error and I found a bug with connect from last year where there was a special character in the document causing the error. In one of the examples, there was a newline character in the name of the document which caused the error. I would suggest creating a case on the DocuSign support site for further investigation (support.docusign.com).

An internal issue ticket has been opened on this matter. When you do contact DocuSign Support, please reference issue number EC-4887.